# How to make MSSQL query data available to Javascript on a page without having to query the database again?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

For a page I'm making with Google Maps API I need to query multiple marker locations and also further information about each marker. I'm using ColdFusion to query the database.

I have mapped out how the process should work roughly

```
 <cfquery datasource="mapInfo" name="markerQuery">
  Select * from locations
 </cfquery>

<cfset arr = ArrayNew(1)>
  <cfoutput query="markerQuery">
    <cfset marker = {#markerid# = 'new google.maps.LatLng(#markerQuery.lat#,#states.lng#)'}>
    <cfset arrayAppend(arr,marker)>
  </cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var markers = <cfoutput>#serializeJson(arr)#</cfoutput>; 
 </script>
```

**How can I retain the query information in Javascript so I can display it in a text box when a marker (or matching button) is clicked?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do is loop over your query, outputting data from the recordset directly into a Javascript array.  Then use this in your JS to loop over, creating markers and infowindows.  Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrMarkers = [];

    <cfoutput query="getData">
        arrMarkers.push({
            lat: #getData.lat#,
            lng: #getData.lng#,
            title: '#JSStringFormat(getData.title)#',
            description: '#JSStringFormat(getData.description)#'
        });
    </cfoutput>


    function initialize() { 
        var latlng, marker;

        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ""
        });

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom:               15,
            center:             new google.maps.LatLng(51.532315,-0.1544),
            mapTypeId:          google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrMarkers[i].lat, arrMarkers[i].lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng, 
                map: map, 
                title: arrMarkers[i].title
            });

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, arrMarkers[i].description);
        }
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just edited the question with some test code. How does it look?

Comment: I'd personally rather not write JS code like `new google.maps.LatLng` into a CFML string

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried this code but the map is not displayed. Shouldn't there be a comma after   title: '#JSStringFormat(getData.title)#' ? Although adding this still doesn't make it work.

Comment: Indeed there should.  Let me try actually running my own code and see what's wrong.  I'm assuming things like you're calling in the Google Maps JS and calling the `initialize` function on window load, but let us know if you need advice on those too

Comment: OK. on adding the comma and adding the correct onload initialize, this is now working. Thanks! In my MSSQL database I have title and address as varchar. Will this datatype work with JSStringFormat?

Comment: yes it should do.  The JSStringFormat is merely to escape things like apostrophes that could otherwise cause you a JS error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25956/discussion-between-jackdamery-and-duncan)